# How I can open a new tab in a Firefox add-on with POST variables?

Tags: firefox, post, firefox-addon

How I can open a new tab in a Firefox add-on with POST variables?

For example, open http://localhost/ with these post variables:

```
a=NOMADE
b=NOWAY
another=IDONTKNOW
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [gBrowser.addTab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-addTab) function is what you want. One of the parameters you pass to that function is `postData`, and allows you to set the postData as you would like it. The MDN documentation for that function also points to [an article on pre-processing POST data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Post_data_to_window#Preprocessing_POST_data). If I read that second article correctly, the POST data needs to be passed in the form of an **nsIInputStream** (specifically created as **nsIMIMEInputStream**). The article provides a sample code snippet for converting from a standard GET style format string (example: `foo=1&goo=somestring`) to the intended format.

**Edit:** So, to use your example, you might do something like this:

```
var myData = "a=NOMADE&b=NOWAY&another=IDONTKNOW";

// TODO: Translate myData into the nsIMIMEInputStream format using the example
// from the second linked article above

// Add the tab, with the variable data
gBrowser.addTab("http://www.example.com/", {postData: myData});
```